# Access Token client->refreshToken stopped working in long-running script

Tags: google-oauth, access-token, refresh-token

I have a script that replicates, on the local filesystem, changes that are made on a particular Google Drive folder and its subfolders.  Script has been working well for a few days, but at noon today, the refresh code stopped working without any explanation that I can find.

Here's a log that demonstrates the issue

```
2023-08-11 08:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 09:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 10:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 11:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 12:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 13:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 14:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 15:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 16:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 17:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 18:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 19:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 20:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 21:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116361) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 21:45:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: Downloading /SongBook/2023-08-12.lst (452 bytes)
2023-08-11 21:45:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: Finished.  1 files found in 0 folders.  (1 files updated, 0 added.  0 new folders).  452 bytes downloaded.
2023-08-11 22:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116363) - nothing to do.
2023-08-11 23:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116363) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 04:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116363) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 05:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116363) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 06:00:06 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116363) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 07:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116363) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 07:49:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: Downloading /SongBook/2023-08-12.lst (452 bytes)
2023-08-12 07:49:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: Finished.  1 files found in 0 folders.  (1 files updated, 0 added.  0 new folders).  452 bytes downloaded.
2023-08-12 08:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116366) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 09:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116366) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 10:00:03 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116366) - nothing to do.
2023-08-12 11:00:02 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook: No change in start page token (116366) - nothing to do.
[12-Aug-2023 12:00:02 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/DriveStuff.php:160
Stack trace:
#0 /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/DriveStuff.php(82): DriveStuff->GetAuth()
#1 /www/htdocs/gdrive/catchupSongBook(52): DriveStuff->GetDriveService()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /www/cgi-bin/GoogleRelated/DriveStuff.php on line 160
```

Here is the code in question.  Comment about line 160 is added for clarity.

```
    $client->setAccessType($accessType);
    $this->GetClientFromDB($clientId        // Handles inserttion of new Client information if necessary; returns as much information as we have otherwise
                        , $clientSecret
                        , $scopes_dummy     // Values below here (including this value) are passed by reference, and are updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $accessToken      // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $tokenType        // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $refreshToken     // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $expires          // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $created          // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                        , $rowId            // Updated by GetClientFromDB()
                            ) ;
    $authHistoryRow = [] ;
    $authHistoryRow['authConfig'] = json_encode($client_json) ;
    $authHistoryRow['clientId'] = $clientId ;
    $authHistoryRow['clientSecret'] = $clientSecret ;
    $authHistoryRow['projectId'] = $client_json[$topKey]['project_id'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['authUri'] = $client_json[$topKey]['auth_uri'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['tokenUri'] = $client_json[$topKey]['token_uri'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['authProviderX509CertUrl'] = $client_json[$topKey]['auth_provider_x509_cert_url'] ;
    $authHistoryRow['appName'] = $appName ;
    $authHistoryRow['scopes'] = implode(',', $scopes) ;
    $authHistoryRow['accessType'] = $accessType ;
    if ((! $rowId) || $client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $accessToken = null ;
        // Refresh the token...
        if ($rowId && $client->isAccessTokenExpired() && $refreshToken) {
            $authHistoryRow['refreshToken'] = $refreshToken ;
            $client->refreshToken($refreshToken) ;
            $accessTokenArray = $client->getAccessToken() ;
(line 160 follows)
            $accessToken = (array_key_exists('access_token', $accessTokenArray) ? $accessTokenArray['access_token'] : false) ;
            $expires = $accessTokenArray['expires_in'] + time() ;
            $authHistoryRow['accessToken'] = $accessTokenArray['access_token'] ;
            $authHistoryRow['expires'] = Date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $expires) ;
            }
        if ((! $accessToken) ) { // Still not able to get authorization.  Talk to user.
            printf("Authorization expired at %s\n", date('Y-m-d H:i', $expires)) ;
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open this link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            printf("Copy verification code\nOr, if 'Page cannot displayed' (or similar), copy entire URL from browser window.\nPaste here: ");
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
            if (preg_match('%^[:/0-9.a-zA-Z_-]+[/][?]code=([^&]+)&%', $authCode, $matches))
                $authCode = urldecode($matches[1]) ;
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessTokenArray = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            //$output = print_r($accessToken, true) ;
            //file_put_contents("access_token.txt", $output) ;
            }
        $accessExpiresEpoch = time() + $accessTokenArray['expires_in'] ;
```

Of course it's likely that this code could apparently be improved in this refresh area (suggestions welcome!), but in any case, it seems(?) the service is not refreshing the token, and I would like to understand why.  How do I find out the cause of $client->getAccessToken() returning null after a refreshToken() operation?  What tests can I perform to ensure the refreshToken() operation actually worked, or why not if not?

An option might be to get a new set of tokens - I can easily take those steps, with some certainty of success.  But more to the point is why it's not working before I do that.  We don't want manual intervention every few days for a process that should just run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app is in testing the refresh token expire after seven days.

go to Google cloud console for your project under the consent screen and set it to production

## Publish app

[image]

## Status now say in production

[image]

Single user apps do not need to be verified.

## video

[How to fix Invalid_grant and expiring refresh token](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYU-Zb4BJC4)

Comment: Ugh, so much effort for verification. Single person accessing his own data and there's all this mess to satisfy some attorney.  And all because we live in a Morgan & Morgan world!  I may dump this project (probably will).  A shame!  But thanks for the answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with verification, it's two separate concepts.  Just click the production button that's it

Comment: I'm sure you're right, Linda, but I don't see it.  Here's a 41-second video showing what I see in this respect.  I hope it leads us in a good direction.  https://youtu.be/OtgcWAHHeNw

Comment: Click publish app button.    I need to do a video on this

Comment: I didn't make a video of it, but I did push that button.  The response was (paraphrased) "App requies verifcation.  Prepare the app for verification."  I looked into the details, and it was because I had created a custom logo (!!!!!!!).  I've dumped the project and created a new one (with new knowledge for which I give you full credit).  Now we'll see in a week.  Thanks.  I've already accepted your answer, earlier today

Comment: okay so you pushed the button but does it now say its in production?  To be 100% clear you do NOT need to verify a single user app.   You just need to click that button so that the app is in production and your refresh tokens will stop expiring.

Comment: Check my update I have made you  picture's      I need to poke the team again to see if we cant get this clarified better.  I get a few people a month with your same issue

Comment: Thanks, Linda.  When the logo has been changed (which I mistakenly thought I must do), this is what that page looks like.  A little different, and implies things won't work until verified.  I don't know if that's the case or not... I started over.    https://web.lovelady.com/stackOverflowImages/question_76890310.jpg

Comment: I have sent a message to the team see if i cant get that message changed.   Make sure you request authorization again after you set it to production.  Come back in a week if it doesn't work.    If it does well good luck happy coding.